# Fastest prime test (can be probabilistic)

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

I am looking for the fastest algorithm to check if a number is a prime. The algorithm doesn't have to be deterministic as long as the chance of it failing is very small. Preferably it should be possible to control the possibility of failure by some parameter like "iteration count".

It would be enough for the algorithm to work for integers <= 10^18, but it would be better if it worked for all integers representable by a C++ `unsigned long long` assuming it being 64 bits (18,446,744,073,709,551,615).

There are already some questions like this one, but they require the algorithm to be deterministic, while for me its fine if it is probabilistic, as long as its "mostly accurate".

Comment: did you actualy try to lookup some resources before asking?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests

Comment: see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481148/primality-testing-for-64-bit-numbers

Comment: @slepic I did, but it doesn't seem to say which one is the fastest

Comment: @YanB. If you follow the wikipedia links to the individual tests, it will give you information on the time complexity. You do have relatively small numbers here though, so this might not be that relevant. In the question I linked the case for numbers up to 64bit is discussed explicitly, although the test there is assumed to be exact. You can make it probabilistic (and reduce time required) by testing only a subset of the Miller-Rabin tests.

Comment: "probability very small" and "mostly accurate" don't really help much. How accurate, what probability?

Comment: Also what means fastest: fastest when given a random prime? fastest when given a random integer? If it's the latter, start by checking if it's even...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, consider Miller-Rabin tests.

Here is a link for testing numbers less than `2^64`: https://www.techneon.com/

You have to test at most three different bases per candidate. To get something probabilistic but about three time faster, just check one randomly chosen out of those three.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Miller-Rabin primality testing algorithm fits your needs perfectly.

Some resources:

[Miller-Rabin Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)

[Implementation and extra information](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/primality_tests.html)